# Matlab: Color individual groups, not individual bars within a group

Tags: matlab

This is my code:

```
Positions=[1:5];
Gap_Duration=[4,4,4,4,4,4;
2,2,2,2,2,2;
3,3,3,3,3,3;
4,4,4,4,4,4; 
0,0,0,0,0,24];
H = barh(Positions,Gap_Duration,'stacked')
set(H([1 3 5]),'Visible','off')
ax = gca;
ax.YTick = [Positions];
ax.YTickLabel = {'AllOut','Port1In','Port2In','DeliverReward','Total Time Duration'};
xlabel('Time')
title('Lever Press Frequency')
```

I want to make the bars on the horizontal y-axes 1 color each (so all 'Deliver Reward bars are red, all 'Port2In' bars are blue, etc.) Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To workaround the issue, generate separate horizontal bar graphs for each row while keeping the width of rest of the elements equals to `NaN` so nothing extra gets plotted. i.e.

```
Lp = length(Positions);  
colors = hsv(Lp);    %Generating group colors (or define custom colors if needed)
hold on;
for k=1:Lp 
    GapD = NaN(size(Gap_Duration));   %Initializing a dummy Gap_Duration matrix
    GapD(k,:) = Gap_Duration(k,:);    %Filling with the content of the current row
    H = barh(Positions, GapD, 'stacked');
    set(H, 'FaceColor', colors(k,:)); %Making the color same for all current bars
    set(H([1 3 5]),'Visible','off');  %This condition is from your code     
end
```

[image: output]